# Cherry pick a range of commits with merge commits

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I need to cherry pick a range of commits, but it fails because in this range I have merge of some branches. 
Is it possible to do it without conflicts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it possible to do it without conflicts?

That depends on what's in the commits-as-converted-to-changesets, vs what's in your own current commit.  It's also not the real issue that I would be concerned about.

> ... it fails because in this range I have merge [commits]

Presumably you mean that `git cherry-pick` complains, upon reaching the merge commit, that you did not specify a `-m` argument.  If you *do* specify a `-m` argument (`git cherry-pick -m 1 ...`), Git complains that you *did* specify a `-m` argument for those commits that are *not* merges.  This is indeed a [conundrum](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conundrum): you must specify `-m 1` while also omitting `-m 1`.

The immediate solution to this problem is to do the cherry-pick piecemeal: pick the first however many non-merge commits (in the correct order and with no `-m` argument), then any merge commits (in the correct order using the correct `-m` argument, which is almost always `-m 1`), then any non-merge commits that follow those, then any merge commits, and so on.

Consider, though, what each `git cherry-pick` actually *does:*  It consists of merging "what they did" with "what you did", where "what they did" is the difference between the parent commit and the child commit, and "what you did" is the difference between the parent commit and your current commit.  The parent and child here are the parent and child of the argument we give to the `git merge` command.  If that argument specifies a merge commit, we must also specify *which* parent—it's no longer just *the* parent—and hence the need for the `-m` flag.  But cherry-picking a merge means that we should take *all the changes introduced by the other leg of the merge*.

This means that in many cases, you will want to *skip* all merge commits when cherry-picking.

Suppose, for instance, we have a graph that looks like this:

```
...--A--B--C--D---E--I   <-- feature-A
      \  \       /
       \  F--G--H
        \
         J--K--L   <-- feature-B (HEAD)
```

Our current commit is commit `L`.  We'd like to obtain, for some particular reason, the equivalent of cherry-picking commits `F` through `H`, as either one big commit or three small commits that we add atop `L`, giving:

```
...--A--B--C--D---E--I   <-- feature-A
      \  \       /
       \  F--G--H
        \
         J--K--L--FGH'   <-- feature-B (HEAD)
```

where `FGH'` is either a three-commit sequence (`F'-G'-H'`) or a single commit that does the same thing as the other three.

We can get this by using `git cherry-pick` and instructing Git to copy commits `F`, `G`, and `H`.  Note that no `-m` flag is required at all as none of these are merge commits.  If we use `-n` to suppress committing each individual pick, and do our own `git commit` at the end, we get one big `FGH'` commit.  (If we let `git cherry-pick` do individual commits, of course, we get `F'` then `G'` then `H'`.)

*Or*, we can instead cherry-pick using merge commit `E`.  Merge commit `E` has *two* parents, namely `D` and `H`.  If we look at the comparison between `D` and `E`, what we'll see as changes are *all the changes imported via the `F-G-H` sequence*.  So we are likely to get, as a single commit, a copy of the `F-G-H` sequence.  If we only *want* a single commit, that may be the way to go.  It's just one `git cherry-pick` rather than three, so it's certainly easier.

There is a caveat, though: this automatically *excludes* any changes that already reached `E` via the `C-D` sequence.  For instance, suppose the change from `C` to `D` is similar to the change from `B` to `F`, so that `D` *includes* everything that is in `F`.  Then the difference between `D` and `E` is only the sum of the differences from `F` to `G` and from `G` to `H`.  (To put this another way, `B` vs `H` shows what happened in the `F-G-H` sequence, but `B` vs `D` *includes* everything that happened in `F`.  Hence `D` vs `E` effectively *hides* the `F` changes, as they're already in `D`.)  Cherry-picking the merge will therefore get us a single commit that has the effects of `G` and `H` combined, but lacks `F`.  ***This might be what you want.  It might not be what you want.  There is no single universal formula for this operation.  You must inspect the commits in question and think about the problem, rather than blindly applying some process here.***

In any case, though, you now have the tools you need to think about the problem and choose a solution.